# Is it lawful to have a dating website that is free for women but charges men initiation +membership fees?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal, any-jurisdiction, sex-discrimination

An American dating [platform](https://unjected.com/pages/women) charges men an up front fee for “verification” and then an ongoing monthly fee for “membership,” while openly stating that “membership is free for women”. Is this discrimination, whether in the U.S. or anywhere else one may care to answer for?

Particularly interested in the USA.

Comment: As the question was asked on law.SE and tagged "is-x-legal" it seems pretty safe to assume OP is asking whether it is legal.

Comment: In UK wouldn't the [Equality Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/contents) make it illegal?